# Who first proved that all comparison-based sorting is Omega(n lg n)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Who first proved that all comparison-based sorting is at least Omega(n lg n)?
Is there a name attached to this lower-bound?  e.g. The SomeGuysLastName Theorem?

Comment: It's such a stunningly obvious result that I'm going to guess it's whoever formalized the concept of a comparison sort (or possibly even before that, expressed in a slightly different way). Surely the only reason they wouldn't produce either this complexity bound, or the `log(n!)` bound on the number of comparisons, is if they didn't have random-access memory and hence had other complexity concerns on their mind. I wait with anticipation for someone who actually knows the literature, though :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My copy of 'Introduction to Algorithms' has this to say in the chapter notes for chapter 8, which is where this bound is discussed:

> The decision-tree model for studying comparision sorts was introduced by Ford and Johnson (1). Knuth's comprehensive treatise on sorting (2) covers many variations of the sorting problem, including the information-theoretic lower bound on the complexity of sorting given here.
>
> (1) Lester R. Ford, Jr. and Selmer M. Johnson. A tournament problem. *The American Mathematical Monthly*, 66:387-389, 1959.
>
> (2) Donald E. Knuth. *Sorting and Searching*, volume 3 of *The Art of Computer Programming*. Addison-Wesley, 1973.

Not a defininite answer to your question, but it's something.

Comment: Haha, that's what I was searching in the moment you wrote your answer

Comment: By coindidence, I'd only just finished reading that chapter a few days ago, so I knew where to look when I saw this question.

Answer (score 1):

Merge sort ( worst case scenario: n log n ) was invented by John von Neumann in 1945, so I think he was the first one to prove it.

But maybe a Greek proved it in 400BC, does it really matter?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Comment: just for trivia debate, that's all.

Comment: A little bit of extra culture always matters!

Comment: The existence of merge sort does not prove that there's an `O(n log n)` lower bound on the number of comparisons required. Knowing that this lower complexity bound exists, though, it does prove that the bound is tight.